# Cannot set a variable to another in a If block of Window cmd

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a basic question.  Struggling with setting variables within a if () bloc.

Below is my code.

```
@echo off 
setlocal 

set var1=variable1
set var1a=%var1%
echo expecting 'variable1' is %var1a%

if 1==1 (
        
    set var2=variable2
    set var2a=%var2%
    echo expecting 'variable2' %var2a%  
)
```

The output is

```
expecting 'variable1' is variable1
expecting 'variable2'
```

How come `echo %var2%` does give an output of variable2.

Is there some basic principle I am missing?

Comment: Within a parenthesised series of instructions (aka "code block") any `%var%`, including `%errorlevel%`, is replaced by the then-current ("parse time") value of that variable when the block syntax is being validated. The syntax `if [not] errorlevel n` may be used, meaning `if the CURRENT errorlevel is [not] "n" OR GREATER THAN "n"`. Otherwise, `delayedexpansion` and `!var!` needs to be used to access the *current* value of the variable, including magic variables like *errorlevel time date cd* and others.  [delayed expansion trap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2128947)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this:

```
@echo off 
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

set var1=variable1
set var1a=%var1%
echo expecting 'variable1' is %var1a%

if 1==1 (
        
    set var2=variable2
    set var2a=!var2!
    echo expecting 'variable2' !var2a!
)
```

more on delayed expansion: https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html